# seaborn horizontal bar plot not showing plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I can plot a normal bar plot with searborn, but when i specify `orient = 'h'` nothing shows up in my plot.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['A','A','A','B','B','C'],columns = ['letters'])
data =df.letters.value_counts()
sns.barplot(x = data.index, y = data)
```

[image]

With **orient**:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to swap x and y when you change orientation.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['A','A','A','B','B','C'],columns = ['letters'])
data =df.letters.value_counts()
sns.barplot(y = data.index, x = data, orient='h')
```

[image]